# How to create a batch file for load test (Visual Studio 2013 Command Prompt)

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2013, command-prompt

I execute my load test using the command **`MSTest /testcontainer:mytest.loadtest`** on VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt. There are two files in my directory: **mytest.loadtest** and **mytest.webtest**. (These two files were enough to execute mytest).

I want to create a batch file to execute mytest.loadtest I don't know much about batch files. Can anyone help?

Comment: what if you put the commands in the bat file and execute it?

Comment: I try to run this in batch file:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest /testcontainer:mytest.loadtest**
But it doesn't work. Command prompt is opening and closing in a short time.

Comment: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest" /testcontainer:LoadTests\mytest.loadtest**
I wrote this command into batch file. The test was executed, problem was solved.

Comment: @ismailcem - I tried your bat file cmd, and I get "File extension specified '.loadtest' is not a valid test extension".  Any thoughts?